# Get certain Javascript value from url in android

Tags: javascript, android, jsoup, javascript-objects

I use Jsoup to parse a url (html page) in android app.this page has multiple `<script>` tags.
I want to retrieve a certain value of  a key  which is a part of a javascript code inside html page.

Value I want to retrieve:

```
 "attr_value_id": "167"
```

code(which is a part of JS code inside html page):

```
window.goodsDetailv2SsrData = {
    goodsDetailv2Language: {
            "goods_desc": "",
            "supplier_top_category_id": "59",
            "parent_id": "1766",
            "is_on_sale": "1",
            "is_virtual_stock": "0",
            "stock": "89",
            "is_init": "1",
            "is_pre_sale": "0",
            "is_pre_sale_end": "0",
            "productDetails": [{
                "attr_id": 101,
                "attr_value_id": "167",
                "attr_name": "Style",
                "attr_name_en": "Style",
                "value_sort": 2,
                "attr_select": 1,
                "attr_sort": 1,
                "left_show": 1,
                "attr_value": "Casual",
                "attr_value_en": "Casual"
     
            }]
        }
}
```

how can i get  value of `attr_value_id` directly ?
and

how can i loop to select  tag that hold this part?

Comment: is the second part of the code section all a json code or mix of kotline and json? kinda confussing.

Comment: It's a javascript object.sorry i don't have  a great knowledge in difference between javascript object and json

Comment: You can't parse JavaScript with Jsoup. In this case I'd use regular expression to get this number from the page source.